# sh to run, close and run again something every 30 minutes

Tags: batch-file, sh

I used a bat to run a python script, and after 30 minutes it killed the process and reopened it. How can i make it in a Fedora linux sh? I used this:

```
title StartWorker 2
:loop        
start "PYworker2" /i python worker.py -st 10
timeout /t 1800 >null        
taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE EQ PYworker2"        
goto loop
```

Comment: Not an answer, but do not use `> null` as this creates a file called `null`; to redirect to the null device use `> nul`...

Comment: So you've shown us a Windows batch script, and you want to know how to do the equivalent using `sh`? You might make that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want would look something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
while true
do
   python worker.py -st 10 &
   sleep 1800
   kill $!
done
```

The magic is that `$!` is the pid of the last backgrounded process.

Welcome to shell programming.  A word of warning: as you learn about it, you'll grow to understand what's missing from the Windows command line.  Ignorance *was* bliss. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the watch command?

`watch -n x python yourscript.Py`

You could include this in a sh file or just run it from the terminal

To set the time just use this

```
watch -n 1800 Python  yourscript.py
```

This should run  your python script every x seconds, however if you an restarting a python script when it's been randomly shut down that it's a different problem.